# Changing the column length of a primary key column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When I try altering a primary key column length in SQL Server, I get the error:

> SQLServerException: The object 'PK_constraint' is dependent on column 'primkey column name'.

After searching around, I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62903913/2653817 and followed its advise as follows:

I execute:

```sql
select name from sys.key_constraints where object_name(parent_object_id) = 'table Name'
```

and use the name returned in the next command:

```sql
alter table [tableName] drop constraint [PK_name]
```

Now I'm able to successfully alter the column length:

```sql
alter table [tableName] alter column [primkey] varchar(nnn) NOT NULL
```

And then I recreate the constraint:

```sql
alter table [tableName] add constraint [PK_name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PRIM_KEY)
```

So far, so good. However, I no longer get the error if I try the alter column command again which seems bad so my question is whether this approach is safe. If you try to alter the column size in SQL Server Management Studio, it says it can't and the only way is to drop the table and recreate.

Comment: If the column definition is the same, the alter column is a no-op. The dependency is not checked in that case. If you mean the SSMS table designer complains, don't use it.

Comment: I used a different column length after recreating the constraint but got no error and the length did change.  I'm worried the integrity has been lost.

Comment: As long as you have the PK constraint in place, the constraint will ensure unique values and integrity. If you are increasing the length, the operation is only meta-data and the constraint doesn't need to be dropped first. You need to drop and recreate the constraint to decrease the length.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm not sure it's true in all cases - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TmL7.png

Comment: @CaiusJard, right, I should have called out variable length columns, not fixed length. The question, though, is varchar.

Comment: I get the error if increasing the length (before the constraint is dropped).  Once I drop the constraint, increase the length, re-add the constraint, that all works but if I try to increase the length again, I thought I'd get the error but I don't.  I did verify that I can't add a duplicate row.  I would just like a good answer as to why I'd get the initial error about the constraint when trying to increase the length but no error after dropping and re-adding it.   I'm just trying to ensure I don't screw up my customers database.

Answer (score 0):

DanGuzman provides the answer for this one in the comments:

VARCHAR columns can have their length increased without dropping the constraint

Other column types may not exhibit the same behavior. Suffice to say; if it allows it, it's safe to do - you didn't lose anything, and your PK still works as a PK :)

Comment: That's true but not for a PRIMARY KEY column, which inherently has a constraint.